# Why is a Read before a Write considered a conflict in transaction serialization?

Tags: database, serialization, transactions, transactional

Theory says that 3 specific problems can occur related to database transactions attempting to be serializable :

- Lost update, where you write over another non-commited write
- Dirty read, where you read a write before it is commited
- Repeatable read, where you read twice without getting the same information

I am however confused because in most of the exercices I have done online, the R before W seems also to be an issue.

In this specific exercice, taken from [here](https://webcms3.cse.unsw.edu.au/COMP9315/16s1/resources/3424), the R before W is highlighted as a problem. 
[image: bdproblem]

My best guest is that R before W is a problem because serialization means that I could change the orders of those instructions without it changing the outcome in both transactions.

The problem is that the solution provided (to push W(y) to the end) makes no sense with that explanation, as pushing it doesn't prevent the order to change after that.

---

Another exercice going in the same direction:
[image]
(Taken from [here](http://cs.ulb.ac.be/public/_media/teaching/infoh417/06_-_concurrency.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a bar which sells beers. It sells Heineken at $3.50. As a customer, I would like to purchase a Heineken in the bar. So I do a `read(Heineken)`, and get the remaining quantity of Heineken, in hopes of buying one. `read(Heineken)` tells me that there is 1 Heineken left, so I am expecting to receive one.

However, at the same time, the bar decides to stop selling Heineken. So the bar does a `write(Heineken, 0)`, and commits.

Now, what happens to me? Will I get a Heineken? I was promised a Heineken, since my `read(Heineken)` told me that I do have one, but there is no Heineken left to be sold. I received incorrect information.

So there are 2 possible outcomes to solve this.

From the suggested solution, we move `write` all the way to the back. This effectively means that the bar can only update its quantities after we settle all other pending `read` transactions. By moving the `write(Heineken, 0)` to the back (after my own `read` transaction commits), I still can get my Heineken, and then the bar can stop selling Heinekens. I will not magically lose my Heineken. In the first example you have shown, it is confusing that `read(Y)` is a problem since, we don't really do anything with `Y` after reading it. But in the more general case where we do something with `Y` after reading it, it will be a problem.

There is also the case where we move the `write` all the way in front, and commit BEFORE I read. This way I am not promised a Heineken that doesn't exist (My `read` will tell me that there are no Heinekens left. I am sad, but at least I get the correct information)